# Why does my context manager __exit__ function run before the computation isn't finished?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, contextmanager

The **exit** function of my custom context manager seemingly runs before the computation is done. My context manager is meant to simplify writing concurrent/parallel code. Here is my context manager code:

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, cpu_count

class managed_pool:
    '''Simple context manager for multiprocessing.dummy.Pool'''
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
    def __enter__(self):
        cores = cpu_count()
        print 'start concurrent ({0} cores): {1}'.format(cores, self.msg)
        self.start = time.time()
        self.pool = Pool(cores)
        return self.pool
    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        print 'end concurrent:', self.msg
        print 'time:', time.time() - self.start
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()
```

I've already tried this script with `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` and it seems to fail all the time.

Here is an example of using the context manager:

```
def read_engine_files(f):
    engine_input = engineInput()
    with open(f, 'rb') as f:
        engine_input.parse_from_string(f.read())
    return engine_input

with managed_pool('load input files') as pool:
    data = pool.map(read_engine_files, files)
```

So, inside of `read_engine_files` I print the name of the file. You'll notice in the `__exit__` function that I also print out when the computation is done and how long it took. But when viewing stdout the `__exit__` message appears way before the computation finished. Like, minutes before the computation is done. But `htop` says all of my cores are still being used. Here's an example of the output

```
start concurrent (4 cores): load engine input files
file1.pbin
file2.pbin
...
file16.pbin
end concurrent: load engine input files
time: 246.43829298
file17.pbin
...
file45.pbin
```

Why is `__exit__` being called so early?

Comment: Where is the code for `read_engine_files`?

Comment: @TomDalton I added in a function for `read_engine_files`. Can someone explain why this is being down voted?

Comment: It's probably being downvoted because you haven't provided a minimal example. Even with the extra code you've posted, now we can't see the `engineInput()` or `engine_input.parse_from_string(f.read())` code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're just calling `pool.map()`? That should block until all the items have been mapped.

If you're calling one of the asynchronous methods of `Pool`, then you should be able to solve the problem by changing the order of things in `__exit__()`. Just join the pool before doing the summary.

```
def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
    self.pool.close()
    self.pool.join()
    print 'end concurrent:', self.msg
    print 'time:', time.time() - self.start
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that an exception occurred. The above code sample does not parse the `type`, `value` or `traceback` arguments of the `__exit__` statement. Thus, an exception occurs (and is not caught earlier), is handed to the exit statement which in turn does not react to it. The processes (or some of them) continue running.